# passing kwargs with multiprocessing.pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyword-argument

I would like to pass keyword arguments to my worker-function with Pool.map().  I can't find a clear example of this when searching forums.

Example Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker((x,y), **kwargs):
    kwarg_test = kwargs.get('kwarg_test', False)
    print("kwarg_test = {}".format(kwarg_test))     
    if kwarg_test:
        print("Success")
    return x*y

def wrapper_process(**kwargs):
    jobs = []
    pool=mp.Pool(4)
    for i, n in enumerate(range(4)):
        jobs.append((n,i))
    pool.map(worker, jobs) #works
    pool.map(worker, jobs, kwargs) #how to do this?   

def main(**kwargs):
    worker((1,2),kwarg_test=True) #accepts kwargs
    wrapper_process(kwarg_test=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

Output:

```
kwarg_test = True
Success
kwarg_test = False
kwarg_test = False
kwarg_test = False
kwarg_test = False
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'dict'
```

The type error has to do with parsing arguments inside of multiprocessing.Pool or Queue, and I have tried several other syntaxes, like making a list of the kwargs; [kwargs, kwargs, kwargs, kwargs], as well as several attempts to include the kwarg in the jobs list but no luck. I traced the code in multiprocessing.pool from map to map_async and got as far as 
`task_batches = Pool._get_tasks(func, iterable, chunksize)`
in pool.py when I encountered the generator structure.  I'm happy to learn more about this in future but for now I am just trying to find out:

Is there a simple syntax for allowing the passing of kwargs with pool.map?

Answer (score 36):

If you want to iterate over the other arguments, use @ArcturusB's answer.

If you just want to pass them, having the same value for each iteration, then you can do this:

```
from functools import partial
pool.map(partial(worker, **kwargs), jobs)
```

[Partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) 'binds' arguments to a function. Old versions of Python [cannot](http://bugs.python.org/issue1398) serialize partial objects though.

Answer (score 17):

The [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` doc](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) states:

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (**it supports only one iterable argument though**). It blocks until the result is ready.

We can only pass one iterable argument. End of the story. But we can luckilly think of a workaround: define `worker_wrapper` function that takes a single argument, unpacks it to args and kwargs, and passes them to `worker`:

```
def worker_wrapper(arg):
    args, kwargs = arg
    return worker(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your `wrapper_process`, you need to construct this single argument from
`jobs` (or even directly when constructing jobs) and call `worker_wrapper`:

```
arg = [(j, kwargs) for j in jobs]
pool.map(worker_wrapper, arg)
```

Here is a working implementation, kept as close as possible to your original
code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker_wrapper(arg):
    args, kwargs = arg
    return worker(*args, **kwargs)

def worker(x, y, **kwargs):
    kwarg_test = kwargs.get('kwarg_test', False)
    # print("kwarg_test = {}".format(kwarg_test))     
    if kwarg_test:
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Fail")
    return x*y

def wrapper_process(**kwargs):
    jobs = []
    pool=mp.Pool(4)
    for i, n in enumerate(range(4)):
        jobs.append((n,i))
    arg = [(j, kwargs) for j in jobs]
    pool.map(worker_wrapper, arg)

def main(**kwargs):
    print("=> calling `worker`")
    worker(1, 2,kwarg_test=True) #accepts kwargs
    print("=> no kwargs")
    wrapper_process() # no kwargs
    print("=> with `kwar_test=True`")
    wrapper_process(kwarg_test=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

Which passes the test:

```
=> calling `worker`
Success
=> no kwargs
Fail
Fail
Fail
Fail
=> with `kwar_test=True`
Success
Success
Success
Success
```

Comment: starmap() https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap can be used for multiple arguments -

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to force yourself to use [map](https://python.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). Just use [apply_async](https://python.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) and pass in your parameters as a dictionary. In this example `batch_parameters` is a list of dictionaries which contain the parameters you want to pass. `future_parameters` keeps a list of tuples of futures and the parameters used to get those futures. In the loop that follows, we wait for the futures to get their results and print the results together with the parameters that were used to generate them.

```
with Pool(parallelism) as pool:
    future_parameters = [(pool.apply_async(f, kwds=parameters), parameters) for parameters in batch_parameters]
    for future, parameters in future_parameters:
        result = future.get()
        print(parameters, "=>", result)
```