# Python multiprocessing - Passing a list of dicts to a pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

This question may be a duplicate. However, I read lot of stuff around on this topic, and I didn't find one that matches my case - or at least, I didn't understood it.

Sorry for the inconvenance.

What I'm trying to do is fairly common, passing a list of kwargs to pool.starmap(), to achieve multiprocessing.

Here's my reduced case:

```
def compute(firstArg, **kwargs): # A function that does things
    # Fancy computing stuff...
    # Saving to disk...
    return True

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    args = [{
        'firstArg': "some data",
        'otherArg': "some other data"
        'andAnotherArg': x*2
    } for x in range(42)]

    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.starmap(compute, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
```

I supposed starmap() will unpack the dict and pass it to compute() as keyword args, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L268) (see also l.46), it sends only keys (or values ?).

So it raises :

```
TypeError: compute() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

It must be a clear, straight forward way to do this... Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a quite similar question : [Python Multiprocessing - How to pass kwargs to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908663/python-multiprocessing-how-to-pass-kwargs-to-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a tiny proxy function:

```
def proxy(Dict):
    return compute(**Dict)

pool.map(proxy, args)
```

Or, since you don't need the `proxy` function polluting the namespace:

```
pool.map(lambda Dict: compute(**Dict), args)
```

Comment: Great ! Just used it in a lambda, that's perfect.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is there anyway to unpack list of dict's? I need to pass the whole dict, not just kwargs. Thanks!

Comment: I have a function like this: def proc(arg):
 os.system(arg['args'] % (arg['exe'], arg['env'], arg['taskName'], arg['searchPath'])) and would like to pass list of dicts within pool thought.

Comment: @New2Python, just don't unpack the individual dictionaries: `pool.map(proc, args)`.