# Python multiprocessing: forwarding kwargs to actor function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, keyword-argument

Note: [Python Multiprocessing - How to pass kwargs to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908663/python-multiprocessing-how-to-pass-kwargs-to-function) does not answer this question.

`procs.append(Process(target=fn, args=(cmd, results), kwargs=**kwargs))`

Pycharm shows syntax error `expression expected` at `**` for `kwargs=**kwargs`.

How should I pass the `kwargs` in without expanding?

I tried to use `kwargs=kwargs` as following

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


c = 0
def fn(a, res, **kwargs):
    print('sleeping: {}'.format(kwargs))
    time.sleep(10)
    global c
    c+=1
    res[a]=c
    print(res)

def test(**kwargs):
    cmds = ['1','2','3']
    procs = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    results = manager.dict()
    for cmd in cmds:
        procs.append(Process(target=fn, args=(cmd, results), kwargs=kwargs))
        procs[-1].start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(a=1, b=2)
```

But got the error:

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: fn() got multiple values for argument 'a'
Process Process-3:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable name `a` in `kwargs` therefore the `a` parameter in function `fn` is defined in both `cmd` in `kwargs`. Try changing the param `a` in `def fn(a, res, **kwargs):` to another name or change `a` in `test(a=1, b=2)` to something like `test(e=1, b=2)`