# How to pass args and kwargs to multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

If I have the following function:

```
def foo(a, b, c=2, d=6):
    return a + b + c + d
```

and I want to parallelize with `multiprocessing`.

How can I pass the following arguments `1, 2, d=10`? i.e. 2 `args` and 1 `kwarg`?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908663/python-multiprocessing-how-to-pass-kwargs-to-function) post, but it does not seem to make it actually parallel. Another possibly useful example was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031681/passing-kwargs-with-multiprocessing-pool-map/36799206), but it is hard to untangle.

Comment: It's all [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async).  I doubt you can get a better answer than just reading the docs in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(a, b, c=2, d=6):
    return a + b + c + d

def foo_callback(result):
    print(result)

def foo_error(error):
    raise error

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

for (a, b, c, d) in ((1, 2, 3, 4),
                     (2, 4, 6, 8),
                     (3, 6, 9, 12)):
    pool.apply_async(
        foo,
        args=(a, b),
        kwds={"c":c, "d":d},
        callback=foo_callback,
        error_callback=foo_error
    )
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Which prints:

```
10
20
30

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I guess that you want to pass the kwds as a dict. The keys need to be strings.

Comment: How can I get rid of the loop and not pass `c` as a parameter?

Comment: Also, all the results are not in a `list` as they usually are with `map`, which is confusing as well. Could you please elaborate on the usage of this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) or [imap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or async function of both function will be more simple.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(args):
    a, b, c, d = args
    return a + b + c + d # or just sum(args)

with Pool(processes=80) as pool:
    iter = ((1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9, 12))
    results = pool.map(foo, iter)

print(results)
```